# How to remove resource name from route helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a route:

```
resources :promo_pages, path: 'promo' do
    get :promo_rubizza, on: :collection, path: 'rubizza', as: :rubizza
end
```

This route is created - `rubizza_promo_pages_path`

But I'd like to have - `rubizza_path`.

**How to implement it?**
I wanted to implement this as `resources :promo_pages, path: 'promo', as: ''`, but it created `rubizza__index_path`

**UPD:** output `rails routes`

```
rubizza_promo_pages GET    /promo/rubizza(.:format)       promo_pages#promo_rubizza
```

Comment: Can you please show us the output of `rails routes` with the `rubizza_promo_pages_path` line?

Comment: updated queston body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In routes, please define the following route (put it on the same level as `resources`, without nesting):

```
get 'promo/rubizza', to: 'promo_pages#promo_rubizza', as: 'rubizza'
```

Then, you should be able to use `rubizza_path` and `rubizza_url`.

Comment: Thanks! I did that, but I wanted to keep the nesting, so I'm asking

Comment: I think that with nesting routes you can only do the solution suggested by Saqib (adding a method in controller)

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is define this path in your `application controller`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def rubizza_path
    rubizza_promo_pages_path
  end

  helper_method :rubizza_path
end
```

in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :promo_pages, path: 'promo' do
   get :promo_rubizza, on: :collection, path: 'rubizza', as: :rubizza
end
```

That way, you can still use rubizza_path in your views, helpers, controllers, etc. but it uses the full nested route instead.

Comment: Thanks, but this methods very many + I thought to implement it by means of routing

Answer (score 0):

Customising the routes names details are available [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes).

What about defining the path based on controller and action?

```
 get 'promo_pages/promo_rubizza', to: 'promo_pages#promo_rubizza', as: :rubizza
```

it will return:

```
 Prefix Verb URI Pattern                          Controller#Action
rubizza GET  /promo_pages/promo_rubizza(.:format) promo_pages#promo_rubizza
```